Inherited a file with messy UV mapping, unsure how to fix
I've inherited a Blender file with all sorts of issues that I think are caused by the UV mapping. Basically, I have a box that keeps pulling artwork from different panels into the wrong places (see screenshots). I know how to use the program with the templates I've been given, but beyond that I'm pretty lost. Any help is appreciated!! Link to the file is here: https://we.tl/t-LlCmcDbJQm 

Hello, in what way is it messy? Also maybe share the file with the image packed inside?

To me this looks like I would expect the package to look like. How do you want it to look?

Sorry, I should have clarified! On the top fold where the tab from the lid tucks into the back of the box, you can see the non-GMO icon wrapping up to that fold. Additionally, the bottom of the box is showing up as solid green, when there isn't any color there. Let me figure out how to attach the file real quick

Ok, just added a link to the post where you can see the file

As you can see if you select the faces of the edge of the box, their UVs are out of the image in the UV Editor, but as the image is supposed to be repeated it's like if they were overlapping the bottom of the image (the Non GMO logo):

You could move these faces over a part of the image that is of the desired color, or in the Image Texture node choose Extend instead of Repeat and it will be as if the the last pixels line of the image is extended indfinitely, so the faces will overlap the green color:


Thank you so much for this detailed explanation!!
